Compatibility of ReactiveMongoTransactionManager and MongoTransactionManager in the same application
We are currently working on a project that requires the use of both ReactiveMongoTemplate and MongoTemplate within the same application. Consequently, we also need to use ReactiveMongoTransactionManager and MongoTransactionManager to manage transactions for non-blocking and blocking operations, respectively.
For now, we added two beans:
@Bean
fun mongoTransactionManager(mongoDatabaseFactory: MongoDatabaseFactory) = MongoTransactionManager(mongoDatabaseFactory)

@Bean
fun reactiveMongoTransactionManager(reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory: ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory): ReactiveMongoTransactionManager {
        return ReactiveMongoTransactionManager(reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory)
}

Then we set in each @Transactional the transaction manager to use depending on whether the Mongo operations are blocking or non-blocking, like so:
@Transactional(transactionManager = "mongoTransactionManager")
@Transactional(transactionManager = "reactiveMongoTransactionManager")

It seems to work correctly in our testing environment, but we aren't sure if it's going to work correctly in production.
Our major concern is whether the transactions will be handled correctly in the production environment. We would like to understand the following:

Is it possible to use both ReactiveMongoTransactionManager and MongoTransactionManager in the same application without causing conflicts or unexpected behaviors?
Are there any known limitations or best practices we should be aware of when configuring and using these transaction managers together?
How does the @Transactional annotation behave in such a setup? Are there any special considerations we need to take into account?

